# How to install and enable brotli compression on LEMP on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, nginx, gzip

I need some help. I have enabled `gzip` compression, but I also want to allow `brotli` compression on my server. I followed many articles available on Google, but none of them helped me to install and enable `**brotli`.

**Did not work:-**

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-and-enable-brotli-compression-on-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04?comment=79124
- https://serverfault.com/questions/957636/how-to-install-brotli-on-nginx-and-ubuntu-18-04
- https://serverfault.com/questions/941767/enable-both-brotli-and-gzip-on-nginx

**I followed all the articled by the digital ocean to install my LEMP stack and WordPress:-**

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-server
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

I think there is no working tutorial available for `brotli.` I also checked the official doc of `Nginx`, but there is not enough information. I followed their doc to install `brotli`, but that did not work for me.

If anyone here can tell me the best and clean method to enable `brotli`. I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compile Brotli from source. And you're right. There's almost no documentation on how to do this. I did this for my own server and I'm now running Brotli. :-)

You will need to either **compile NGINX with Brotli**, or **compile a Brotli dynamic module** and add to an already-built NGINX.

Here's the script I documented for the second choice: https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-brotli-to-a-built-nginx-instance

Hope this helps you.